# Why Rust HashMap is slower than Python dict?

Tags: python, rust, hashmap

I wrote scripts performing the same computations with dict and hashmap in Rust and in Python. Somehow the Python version is more than 10x faster. How is that happens?

Rust script:
`

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let now = Instant::now();

    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    for i in 0..1000000 {
        h.insert(i, i);
    }

    let elapsed = now.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed: {:.2?}", elapsed);
}
```

Output:   `Elapsed: 828.73ms`

Python script:

```
import time

start = time.time()
d = dict()

for i in range(1000000):
    d[i] = i

print(f"Elapsed: {(time.time() - start) * 1000:.2f}ms")
```

Output:  `Elapsed: 64.93ms`

The same is for string keys. I searched for different workarounds about different hashers for HashMap but none of them is giving more than 10x speed up

Comment: First, python structures are backed by highly optimized C code - in simple cases where the "glue" is minimal, it's reasonable to expect Python to be quite fast. `range()` in particular is a C-backed function, which may be faster than iteration and manually adding values in Rust.

Second, it's really difficult to do performance calculations like this - all kinds of things come into play, such as warm-up time and memory caching. Isolated tests like this are often meaningless.

Comment: For example, I just ran your python script in an online IDE, and got  2500+ms. It's not surprising that would be slower, but it shows the impact the vagaries of system and environment have. It isn't a simple matter of some systems being faster or slower in all cases, either.

Comment: @EdwardPeters said most of the issues of your benchmarking, except maybe one: the hashing scheme used by your hash table, has well as the hash table algorithm itself, have a great, *great* impact on performance, and since there isn't one that is better than any other in any situation, it's entirely possible that the one Python is using is different from the one Rust is using, and just faster on this contrived example.

Comment: You probably forgot `--release` in the `cargo run` command.

Comment: Saying more things, one of the biggest things in performance is memory management. As anyone who's worked in a manually memory managed language - `C`, `C++` or `Rust` knows, it's a pain. Garbage collection is a much more hands-off process, but can have major and unpredictable performance impacts. One reason you'd think of `Rust` as a "fast" language is that it *isn't* garbage collected, but that's not a benefit that will become apparent in a simple case like this where Python garbage collection has nothing to do.

Comment: More more things, Rust is a low level language, which does not necessarily mean faster - it means it gives the programmer a great deal of power to optimize. If the programmer does not use that power - as in this case - you wouldn't expect a performance advantage from that. Similarly, the compiler may be able to perform optimizations that an interpreted language can't - but if the process being executed is this simple, there may be none such to do, or the code may be so simple that even an interpreted languages' JIT optimizations may be equivalent.

Comment: From a short look into strace I would agree that this is memory management. Looks like Python takes about twice as memory based on the mmap calls. And if the hash in rust is created with_capacity it is much faster than before (and faster than Python if compiled with optimization) - looks like it had to copy the full data whenever it grew will Python likely only has smaller references to the data (but thus needs more memory).

Comment: Much more broadly, though, and this should be the takeaway - objectively comparing the performances of languages is *hard*. Even professionally done benchmarks may not reflect the reality of code performance, especially because there is no "single number" of a language's speed. To begin to make the attempt you need to be controlling for the initial state of your system including concurrently running processes and the state of the memory hierarchy.

Comment: @Finomnis I tried this locally and, indeed, Rust built with `--release` is much faster than Python. That may be of interest, but OCaml is a bit slower than Python.

Comment: @Finomnis I mean, that could certainly be the case, but it isn't one or another - there's a million things that can impact performance. Without a much more controlled experiment I don't think there's value in diagnosis.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich « Looks like Python takes about twice as memory based on the mmap calls » Perhaps because Python does not store raw integers in its potentially heterogeneous `dict`; it stores dynamically allocated objects (which in the end all contain an integer in this example) which are much bigger.

Comment: @EdwardPeters In general, yes, but there should never be a case where such a simple Rust code is 10x slower than its Python equivalent. That would be a major flaw in Rust's `HashMap` implementation, given that Rust is specifically written with performance in mind. We are not talking percentages here, we are talking orders of magnitude.

Comment: @Finomnis That makes sense, barring extremes. Actually, looking at it more I'm surprised the Rust compiler doesn't just optimize that away. Can it not tell that initializing the hashmap doesn't have side effects or create other references somewhere?

Comment: @Finomnis there are absolutely such cases though, for instance allocation is *extremely* expensive for rust, much more so than for python, python also has more opportunities for tricks (e.g. concatenating an empty string is a no-op, the entire thing is bypassed and you just get the original source back), so regularly people take allocation-heavy python code, translate it to similarly allocation-heavy rust (which you'd usually avoid) and performances decrease.

Comment: @EdwardPeters The hash map has 1 million entries, I think computing its value at compile time is a bad idea. It would bloat the executable a lot.

Comment: An other common pitfall is IO: rust line-buffers stdout, always, while python lets libc do its thing, meaning full buffering, which is a lot more efficient especially when writing out lots of very small lines. This is compounded by the formatting machinery of rust famously being... [quite slow](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76490).

Comment: @Finomnis I'm not saying "Do it at compile time", I'm saying "Don't do it" - no value is ever read, nothing I can see can throw an error... it's a dead variable. I would expect the compiler to just treat that as a no op.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Ah, now I get you. Yah, I guess it could. I suspect it's too complicated for the compiler to realize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust by default doesn't have optimizations enabled, because it's annoying for debugging. That makes it, in debug mode, slower than Python. Enabling optimizations should fix that problem.

This behaviour is not specific to Rust, it's the default for most compilers (like `gcc/g++` or `clang` for C/C++, both require the `-O3` flag for maximum performance).

You can enable optimizations in Rust by adding the `--release` flag to the respective `cargo` commands, like:

```
cargo run --release
```

Python doesn't distinguish between with or without optimizations, because Python is an interpreted language and doesn't have an (explicit) compilation step.

This is the behavior of your code on my machine:

- Python: ~180ms
- Rust: ~1750 ms
- Rust (with `--release`): ~160ms

Python's `dict` implementation is most likely written in C and heavily optimized, so it should be similar in performance to Rust's `HashMap`, which is exactly what I see on my machine.

Comment: An other component to this recurring "issue" is that Rust defaults to a very safe but relatively expensive hash function (SipHash 1-3). Meanwhile the hash function for integers in Python is literally the identity function, so it is essentially free to compute.

Comment: @Masklinn Makes sense. I guess that explains why Rust isn't faster, as I would have initially expected. The overhead of having dynamically allocated, garbage collected types (Python) about evens out the overhead of a more complicated hash function (Rust).

Comment: FWIW when the hashmap is performance critical and not subject to potentially malicious user input, looking at something like fnv, ahash, city, ... is usually suggested (though needs to be benchmarked as they might have different conflict patterns). Integers are very small so the hash should have little to no setup cost. It's even possible to pare down the general hash in order to only support the specific case of e.g. 32 bit values.

Comment: (by comparison "xxhash" has a lot of setup but is extremely fast when it strides, so [it's good for large keys](https://github.com/shepmaster/twox-hash#64-bit))